# Publish bot - Bing Chanel "Submit for Review" button is disabled

Tags: botframework

I am trying to publish a chatbot to Bing channel. I have filled in all the mandatory information, but the Submit for Review button is still disabled, any tips why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For channel configuration issues, the best way is to submit your problem on [BotBuilder GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) and include your bot name, bot handle and app ID as you registered in the [Bot Developer Portal](https://botframework.com)

Comment: Post it to GitHub and was fixed quickly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repro your issue. It seems that the "Tags for your Bot" field is also mandatory, even though is not marked as it in the UI.

Try filling that field and you will see the button will become enabled.

Comment: thanks heaps for trying, i tried that too but it is still disabled, i will submit a github issue.

Comment: are you filling all the values in the form, including the icon?